# Which anime does the idea of the afterimage comes from?

Tags: tropes

In *Dragon Ball*, Goku has an "after image" technique, where he moves so fast that he leaves a false image of himself in the air, where actually there is nothing. I've seen this idea also in *One Punch Man* , where both Speed of Sound Sonic and Saitama do it, and now I've just seen it in *Kimetsu no Yaiba*, when Tanjiro is fighting a demon, the demon attacks where he's supposed to be, and he was no longer there because he moved so fast and left a fake image of him in his place.

Which anime does the idea of the afterimage comes from? Is it an idea from *Dragon Ball* or was it done before it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it an idea from Dragon Ball or was it done before it?

It was done before it.

> Which anime does the idea of the afterimage comes from?

You'll need to elaborate on that question. But even if you did it'll be an opinionated and subjective question. Here's why:

1. Goku's (technically not his original) move is **残像拳** (zan zou ken - "after-image" is an acceptable translation). Do you accept the similar concept **残影** (zan ei - "after-shadow") to be included? And if you do, *Fist of the North Star* used such move **残影蠍拳** (after-shadow scorpion punch).
2. You mention "anime" but they all originate from comics. Do you want the "first anime" or "first comic" incorporating that technique?
3. *Ninja Hattori-kun* from his self-titled series runs so fast like a Ninja (duh) which leaves a trail of his after-shadow. Do these meet the criteria or not?
4. Speaking of Ninjas, Goku used Zan Zou Ken against Sergeant Major Ninja Murasaki at the Red Ribbon facility. Murasaki approved Goku's technique to be the true form of the old-school Ninja technique **Bunshin**, i.e. cloning. Readers may disagree because we've seen hard-core cloning such as Tien literally splitting himself into actual copies, which blows Goku's move out of the water, but I would trust the words of a high ranking professional Ninja rather than keyboard warriors, especially when it comes to **Ninjyutsu** (Ninja-techniques). Assuming you accept Goku's Zan Zou Ken to be categorized as Bunshin, now we're entering the rabbit hole since Bunshin is a Ninjyutsu used by all kinds of Ninjas.

Decades and centuries ago, people would enjoy **紙芝居** (kamishibai), where a story-teller would entertain the audience by flipping pages of hand-drawn images. If you accept such media to qualify as an ultra-low FPS animation, it would then be next to impossible to track down the first appearance of such Ninjyutsu in the history of anime.